# Groovy SQL batch

Tags: sql, groovy

I've read about Groovy's `batch` method. The part that I'm confused about is `int batchSize`. What does it do and what is really for? I've made sample scripts using `batch` method and it doesn't seem to make a difference. I just want another point-of-view.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear: are you talking about the `Sql` class [withBatch](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withBatch(int, groovy.lang.Closure)) statement? (sorry for bad link format, can't get it to work properly)

Comment: Yes, sorry. `withBatch(int batchSize, String sql, Closure c)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a large number of SQL queries to run, you can either run them one by one (which can be very slow) or all at once (which can flood the database). And you may not even know in advance how many queries you will have (consider for example storing a bunch of user generated structures).

Batch processing allows you to take the middle ground and run up to `batchSize` queries at once. When they finish, the code will run the next `batchSize` queries. And even if you are not dealing with with a potentially large number of queries, `withBatch` is a shortcut to calling [the appropriate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()) Java methods for executing many SQL queries.

As for why it makes no difference in your code, you would have to tell us more about how you are using it and what kind of difference you were expecting but didn't experience.

Comment: Thanks. I'm only executing a handful of queries that's why it didn't make a difference. This really helps.